# Relative Complementary Sets proof

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Question :

Prove $A-(A-B)=A\cap B$

Choose $x\in A-(A-B)$
$\begin{aligned}
&\iff x\in A \land x\notin (A-B) \quad \text{Definition of Relative Complementary Set} \\
&\iff x\in A \land \left(x\notin A \lor x\in B\right) \quad \text{Definition and De Morgan} \\
&\iff \left(x\in A \land x\notin A\right) \lor \left(x\in A \land x\in B\right) \quad \text{Distribution's Rule} \\
&\iff \mathbf{F}\lor \left(x\in A \land x\in B\right) \text{Negation's Rule} \\
&\iff x\in A \land x\in B \quad \text{Identity Rule} \\
&\iff x\in A\cap B \quad \text{Definition of intersections}
\end{aligned}$

Is my prove correct? Please tell me if is anything wrong. Thanks

Comment: As a matter of style, instead of "Choose...", write "For every $x$ we have..." although if I was marking this I'd give 10 out of 10.

Comment: Yes, i think so...

Comment: And hey, i don't think that "definition and De Morgan" (second row) is the correct reason... could you tell me please?

Comment: I missed that. We have $x\not \in A-B\iff$ $ ((x\not \in A)\lor (x\in A\land x\in B)).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct.  There is nothing wrong.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. :)